# How can I create multiple columns at once using R, preferably dplyr or data.table?

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I would like to create multiple new variables based on the values within existing columns of my data frame.

Here is a simplified version of my data:

```
df <- structure(list(City = structure(c(5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Chico", 
"Lawndale", "Los Angeles", "San Francisco", "San Jose"), class = "factor"), 
    yq = c("20071", "20111", "20074", "20124", "20111", "20124"
    ), cyq_total = c(15582L, 33668L, 40848L, 89028L, 1069L, 178L
    )), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

```
           City    yq cyq_total
1      San Jose 20071     15582
2 San Francisco 20111     33668
3 San Francisco 20074     40848
4   Los Angeles 20124     89028
5         Chico 20111      1069
6      Lawndale 20124       178
```

The variable cyq_total represents the number of job vacancies in a city in a year-quarter (yq). I would like to create new variables called "Vac20071", "Vac20111", and so on where the value is cyq_total for a given city for a given year and quarter.

This is simplified for my example, but essentially I want the column Vac20071 to display how many vacancies each city had in the year-quarter 20071. Similarly for other year-quarters.

Desired output:

```
  City          yq    cyq_total Vac20071 Vac20111 Vac20074 Vac20124
  <fct>         <chr>     <int>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1 San Jose      20071     15582    15582        0        0        0
2 San Francisco 20111     33668        0    33668    40848        0
3 San Francisco 20074     40848        0    33668    40848        0
4 Los Angeles   20124     89028        0        0        0    89028
5 Chico         20111      1069        0     1069        0        0
6 Lawndale      20124       178        0        0        0      178
```

The code I have to do this works, but is not efficient. I'm looking for a better way to generate the same results other than copy/pasting the same code with slight changes:

```
df <- df %>% group_by(City) %>% mutate(Vac20071 = max(ifelse(yq == '20071', cyq_total, 0)))
df <- df %>% group_by(City) %>% mutate(Vac20111 = max(ifelse(yq == '20111', cyq_total, 0)))
df <- df %>% group_by(City) %>% mutate(Vac20074 = max(ifelse(yq == '20074', cyq_total, 0)))
df <- df %>% group_by(City) %>% mutate(Vac20124 = max(ifelse(yq == '20124', cyq_total, 0)))
df <- df %>% group_by(City) %>% mutate(Vac20111 = max(ifelse(yq == '20111', cyq_total, 0)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the data in wide format and then join.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
 pivot_wider(names_from = yq, values_from = cyq_total, names_prefix = 'Vac') %>%
 left_join(df, by = 'City')

# A tibble: 6 x 7
#  City          Vac20071 Vac20111 Vac20074 Vac20124 yq    cyq_total
#  <fct>            <int>    <int>    <int>    <int> <chr>     <int>
#1 San Jose         15582       NA       NA       NA 20071     15582
#2 San Francisco       NA    33668    40848       NA 20111     33668
#3 San Francisco       NA    33668    40848       NA 20074     40848
#4 Los Angeles         NA       NA       NA    89028 20124     89028
#5 Chico               NA     1069       NA       NA 20111      1069
#6 Lawndale            NA       NA       NA      178 20124       178
```

---

Equivalent approach in `data.table` suggested by @chinsoon12

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)
dcast(df,City ~ paste0("Vac", yq), value.var="cyq_total", fill=0L)[df, on=.(City)]
```

Answer (score 2):

An option using `data.table` with matrix numeric indexing:

```
cols <- paste0("Vac", unique(df$yq))
setDT(df)[, (cols) := 0L]
df[, (cols) := {
    m <- as.matrix(.SD)
    ix <- match(paste0("Vac", yq), cols)
    m[cbind(rep(1L:.N, each=length(ix)), rep(ix, .N))] <- cyq_total
    as.data.table(m)
}, City, .SDcols=cols]
df
```